# Как заставить callback, вызванный из await-функции отработать до ее завершения

Tags: javascript, async-await, callback

```
(async () => {
  let anything;

  await anyNoReturnFunctionFromLibrary(arg1, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw(err);
    anything = result;
  });

  anotherFunction(anything.property1);
})();
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-то заставить отработать callback функции  anyNoReturnFunctionFromLibrary до вызова функции  anotherFunction, чтобы переменная anything проинициализировалась. Вариант вставить anotherFunction в callback работает, но он мне не нравится, т.к. логика будет расширяться, и всю ее придется делать в callback

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Сделать из коллбечной функции промиз. Стандартное решение